# How to refresh text innerHTML itself to display while the video is playing?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Using on Firefox, I have subtitle that will match with video while it playing. It is there but it does not show subtitle text underneath the video but it strange if I click the video progress bar or drag it, the text will show up. I want subtitle text to show up itself while video is playing. Anyone can help me out?

Here a code,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 included Javascript....</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Test" charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                var subtitleArray = new Array(); //stored all values from XML caption file

                function loadXMLDoc(dname)
                {
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
                    xhttp.send();

                    return xhttp.responseXML;
                }

                function getCaption()
                {
                    alert("get caption");

                    var tempArray = new Array();
                    var c = document.getElementById('container');

                    captionsDoc = loadXMLDoc("captions.xml");
                    x=captionsDoc.getElementsByTagName('text');

                    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                    {
                        var tempArray = new Array();
                        tempArray[0] = x[i].getAttribute('start'); // get start time
                        tempArray[1] = x[i].getAttribute('dur'); // get duration time
                        tempArray[2] = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue; // get text

                        subtitleArray[i] = tempArray; //put all 3 values in array


                    }

                    //c.innerHTML = subtitleArray[0][2];

                }

                function load(){

                    alert("run video");

                    getCaption();



                        document.getElementById('caption').addEventListener('play', function (){

                            var t = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;

                            video = document.getElementById('caption');

                            //t.innerHTML = video.currentTime;

                            var text = "", cap = "";

                            for( var i = 0; i < subtitleArray.length;i++)
                            {
                                //alert("looping");
                                //var currentTime = video.currentTime();
                                var cueStart = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][0]);
                                var cueEnd = cueStart + parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][1]);

                                cap = subtitleArray[i][2];

                                if (video.currentTime >= cueStart && video.currentTime <= cueEnd) {
                                   text = cap;   
                                }
                                var t = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = text;
                                //t.innerHTML = text;
                            }

                        }, false);  


                }



            window.onload = load;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div>
            <video id="caption" width="320" height="240" controls>
                <source src="caption.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="caption.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
                <source src="caption.webm" type="video/webm" />
            </video> 
        </div>
        <div id= "container">
        </div>
        <div id = "timer">  
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

function getCaptions() role is to parse timing and text from xml and store into subtitle array. 
function load() call it to run and to match timing with video time to display subtitle text.

Comment: Use the timeupdate event?

Comment: I believe I already use addEventListener('play', function(){}) as timeupdate that get video current time and match it.

Comment: @StudentIT this may be of interest http://popcornjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

As long as you execute a javascript function, the html on the screen will never refresh. And it seems that you're running an infinite loop inside the load() function.
Thus the problem.